# Can you truly fall asleep in two minutes with this military technique?

Tags: sleep

[The military secret to falling asleep in two minutes | The Independent](https://redd.it/9csosd).

> The trick is reportedly used by the US [army](https://www.independent.co.uk/topic/Army) to help them fall asleep in situations that are less than peaceful, such as on battlefields.
>
> Detailed in the book *Relax and Win: Championship Performance*, 1981, the technique is thought to have been developed by army chiefs to ensure soldiers didn’t make life-threatening mistakes due to exhaustion.
>
> Here’s how to do it:
>
> 1. Relax the muscles in your face, including tongue, jaw and the muscles around the eyes
> 2. Drop your shoulders as far down as they’ll go, followed by your upper and lower arm, one side at a time
> 3. Breathe out, relaxing your chest followed by your legs, starting from the thighs and working down
> 4. You should then spend 10 seconds trying to clear your mind before thinking about one of the three following images:
>
>    - You’re lying in a canoe on a calm lake with nothing but a clear blue sky above you
>    - You’re lying in a black velvet hammock in a pitch-black room
>    - You say “don’t think, don’t think, don’t think” to yourself over and over for about 10 seconds.
>
> The technique is said to work for 96 per cent of people after six weeks of practice.

[Michael Grothaus](https://www.fastcompany.com/90253444/what-happened-when-i-tried-the-u-s-armys-tactic-to-fall-asleep-in-two-minutes) wrote

> So I can confidently say this decades-old technique worked for me. **Mind you, it didn’t work every night.** Some nights during that second week I didn’t get that “release” after my visualization. But as the weeks went on, the trick seemed to work more often than not. And it seemed to work more effectively when I visualized myself in a velvety hammock instead of in a canoe, so it helps to switch up visualizations to see what works best.

But this [r/IsItBullshit](https://redd.it/bblx9i) post judges this BS.

1. sterlingphoenix. [49 points 1 year ago](https://old.reddit.com/r/IsItBullshit/comments/bblx9i/isitbullshit_the_army_has_a_breathing_technique/ekjnkgf/).

> That's bullshit. For one thing, that would instantly become widely available. It's not the kind of thing you can ke[e]p secret.

2. MisterSlosh. [16 points 1 year ago.](https://old.reddit.com/r/IsItBullshit/comments/bblx9i/isitbullshit_the_army_has_a_breathing_technique/ekjs1vc/)

> Bullshit . Was army, no technique, it's literally just being 100% exhausted all the time that you can sleep as soon as you stop moving.

3. devilsadvocate09. [9 points 1 year ago.](https://old.reddit.com/r/IsItBullshit/comments/bblx9i/isitbullshit_the_army_has_a_breathing_technique/ekjqofe/)

> Veteran here, it is bullshit, you pretty much become accustomed to catching a few minutes of sleep whenever the opportunity arises, especially in combat zones where long duration sleep can be hard to come by.
>
> I would argue that the really short naps are more of a meditation state than sleep state.

Comment: Duplicate: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/41528/37236

Comment: @Laurel I honestly didn't see that other answer when I wrote this, but I don't think this duplicates completely. That other question doesn't quote Reddit comments, as I do, that further counters the claim that the military doesn't use this trick and that this trick can't stay confidential.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110512/discussion-on-question-by-accounting-can-you-truly-fall-asleep-in-two-minutes-wi).

Comment: I cleaned this up for you. I hope your bounty fetches good answers.

Comment: I'm leaving this link here for myself or anyone else who wants to write answer. I can't get to it today :) Should  be a good starting point.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279320/